# Include Login Side Box which uses the Secure Module -- Play Framework

Tags: security, authentication, playframework

I'm working on this for days now and I just can't figure it out..

My question is: Is it possible to alter the login.html file in the view.secure folder, so that I could include it in another html-file with #{include 'views/login.html'}, let's say in the index.html, as a login-sidebox, and how could this work?

Comment: By the way, why do you want to override it? Why not simply create a new component for sidebox login and have another component for full screen login?

Comment: because it would be nice to show the sidebox on many components, like the info.html, about.html and so on, do you understand that?

Comment: Off course, that is a common case. But still, why override and not create a new one? There is absolutely no difference/advantage in override rather than creating a new component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all of your friendly assistance i solved the problem!

I included the login-form into all sites i want it in, and when I get logged in or logged out, I use the onAuthenticated()/onDisconnected() to redirect to the wanted site!

But there is one problem left! If the case appears that a error message is displayed, like "User not existing" or something, it is not possible to handle that case.. it would be nice if you could also help me with that.

Comment: Hi Robert, please open a new question with this message, and add the code samples that are failing in that question so we can help you.

Comment: i already solved it, should i post a new answer with my own complete solution for others who have the same problem?

Comment: Hi @Robert, ideally post a new question with the answer. This is encouraged in SO, and it will help users having the same issue, besides separating both issues. If you post it here you would mix 2 issues in one question and it can get confusing :) Btw, congrats on solving it! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Move the code to a tag. Simply move the file "login.html" under tags folder, and then you can use it as:

```
#{login /}
```

That said, be careful. I don't have the code here but it may be that login is using some vars. If that's the case, you'll need to pas the vars to the tag and modify the tag slightly. For example, assume you have a var called "name" in the tag. You'll have to change "name" to "_name" in the tag and pass the var as parameter in the tag, as follows:

```
#{login name:name /}
```

This is the standard behavior of [tags](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/templates#TagstagName). You can check existing tags in the "samples" folder of the framework for more help.

Comment: thank you for your answer! that was also my idea at the beginning, but when i added the @With(Secure.class), as mentioned in the documentation, my firefox spit out a routing error. And if I remove this line of code now, just a blank white page is shown.

Comment: EDIT: Is it possible that play still trys to redirect to the login.html which is in the views.secure folder?

Comment: firefox tells me that I may have deactivated cookies, but that's not the case.

Comment: It clearly is redirecting you since it used searching routes files to find where to go with non connected users.

Comment: please edit the question and add the full error as Play shows it (or Firefox) :)

Comment: so, is it possible to redirect to another page where the login fields are included as a tag?

Comment: @Pere: here is my firefox error Redirect Loop

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

The browser has stopped trying to retrieve the requested item. The site is redirecting the request in a way that will never complete.

    * Have you disabled or blocked cookies required by this site?
    * NOTE: If accepting the site's cookies does not resolve the problem, it is likely a server configuration issue and not your computer.

Comment: @robert ok, this is a problem in the code you are using, specifically your routes and the controller. In the controller you must be doing a redirect (calling a method like foo()) and routes brings you back to a method that calls foo() again. That is, you have an infinite loop of redirects. Recheck the routes file and the code :)

Comment: ok now it's working, but i've got another problem, I mentioned it in the answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Probably with `#{extends 'index.html' /}` combined with `#{doLayout /}` as shown in [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/templates#inheritance).

Comment: at first, thank you for your quick answer, but that wouldn't work, because I want the sidebox to show up on different sites, like the Welcome-Page, the Info-Page and so on.. but when the User logs in, he should be redirected to his Profile-Page, where this sidebox is not existent.